# Upgraded Android App not Getting New versionName

Tags: android, version, upgrade, google-play, android-library

I am using this code to get the app's "version name" and then send it to my server:
`String appversion = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(act.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;`

When I have v1.0 of the app installed on my phone and upgrade the app via Google Play to v1.0.1, the app still sends "1.0" as the `versionName`.

If I "Force Close" the app and then open it, it still reports "1.0".

If I "Force Close" and "Clear Data", it still reports "1.0".

If I uninstall the app from my phone and then download v1.0.1, **only then does the version name gets reported as "1.0.1"**.

Any ideas why this would be happening or what I can to do fix the problem?

Edit:
This app is one of several targets / apks that are connected to an Android Library. There is a Manifest in the Android Library and a Manifest in each target apk. My understanding is that the each apk will use it's own Manifest (and the incorrect version numbers don't match the number in the library's Manifest either) but I thought I should mention this.

Comment: For debugging, add a Toast that shows the version name in your app. If it's wrong there, you can already exclude that it's an error with your reporting system.

Comment: It appears to be an error with the upgrade system. It does report the correct version if I do a fresh install of the app. Just not when I upgrade from the previous version.

Comment: Its possible that you didn't get the updated apk the first time, as Google Play takes a while to sync updates across all its servers. Then when you uninstalled and reinstalled the app, you got the new one.

Comment: The app has been on the Market for more than 24 hours. When I go to the screen for the app in Google Play it shows the new version (v1.0.1) and has an "Open" button, indicating that I have v1.0.1 on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check [this](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en&topic=2365760&ctx=topic) offical help!

You are mentioning versionName, but the thing which helps distinguish app versions is **versionCode** defined in your manifest file.

So if this is old version manifest:

```
//...    
package="com.your.app"
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="MyApp V1.0"
//...
```

... new one should look like this:

```
//...    
package="com.your.app"
android:versionCode="2" 
android:versionName="MyApp V1.1"
//...
```

Also notice that google takes 12-48 hours to publish new version online.

Comment: Thanks but my Manifest has been updated for each version. I don't even think Google Play will accept a Manifest that doesn't have a higher versionCode and versionName